# Use NLP parsing to reference a common object

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am new to the whole NLP scene, and so please forgive me if this is a stupid question or if I don't seem to be articulating the question very well.

What I want is to parse a sentence like: **"John has a book but Jane does not"** and make the program understand that *John* and *Jane* are referencing a common object - a *book*.

Another example to make this a little more clear: **"Jim is smart but his brother is not"**. Here, the program has to understand that the word *smart* is used to describe both *Jim* and *his brother*.

Is what I want even possible? How do I put this logic into code? What parser should I use?  
{{ (>_<) }}

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible way  to start is by exploring the syntactic dependencies among words, using the output of a parser, for instance, for the sentence:

> Jim is smart but his brother is not

the output of spaCy's parser:

[image]

You will have to explore the PoS-tags and syntactic dependencies, probably a first approach is to use manual rules.

Comment: I was hoping someone could help me with the syntactic logic, i.e., the exact rules that would solve this.

Comment: try it, and see where it fails, rewrite the rules, give it a try.